# How can I deploy my smart contract with someone else's wallet?

Tags: metamask, wallets, nft, erc-721, smart-contract-wallets

I am new to the nft business. If I want to hire a developer and ask him to develop smart contract and deploy it on chain, then How Will I able to withdraw money/minting price, since the developer has deploy the contract from his account and as far as I know the account that deploys the contract is considered as the owner of the contract. Even If I give access to him of one of my account, Still the privacy concerns stays. What shall I do?

Please help, It's urgent.

Answer (score 0):

Have the developer teach you how to deploy.

If they developer deploys using their wallet then now or later, that developer will be able to claim they are the "owner" of the contract and claim all your secondary royalties on NFT sales.

And P.S. that will be the same time that their email address and phone number stop working.

Comment: So how to handled this? I mean isn't there nay secure way to do it? Since I have a sense there should be a standard way to do it.

Comment: Yes. The secure way is that they need to explain the deployment process to you. There are many deployment processes and I prefer Remix.